# vb.net Why doesn't My.setting make my form's location sticky?

Tags: vb.net

I can't get my form's screen location to be sticky.

My form is named "GUI".

I added the x & y variables to project > Settings tab.

```
' app boots, form loads, and should set its screen location...
Private Sub GUI_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    IF Not ( MY.Settings.Window_Location_Setting_X = 0  And  MY.Settings.Window_Location_Setting_Y = 0 )
        Me.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual
        Me.Location = New Point( MY.Settings.Window_Location_Setting_X, MY.Settings.Window_Location_Setting_Y )
    END IF
END SUB

' I click and drag form to new locatin.......
Private Sub GUI_LocationChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.LocationChanged
    MY.Settings.Window_Location_Setting_X = sender.Location.X
    MY.Settings.Window_Location_Setting_Y = sender.Location.y
End Sub
```

Comment: `OnLocationChanged` is called before `OnLoad`, so you always have the default position. Move that code to, e.g., the `ResizeEnd` event handler -- I assume the Form could also be moved to a position where one of the coordinates is `0` -- Some debugging should make the sequence clear

Comment: First things first, for that code to compile, you must have Option Strict Off. That's bad. You should basically have Option Strict On at the project level all the time and then turn it Off at the file level only where it's required. Even then, you should use partial classes to keep the code in those files to an absolute minimum.

Answer (score 1):

This seems clearer and much shorter.  The forms StartPosition is set to  FormStartPosition.Manual in the designer.  **Note** that the .Shown event is used instead of the .Load event.

```
'My.Settings.Loc  is  System.Drawing.Point
Private Sub Form1_Shown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Shown
    Me.Location = My.Settings.Loc
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_ResizeEnd(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.ResizeEnd
    My.Settings.Loc = Me.Location
End Sub
```

[ResizeEnd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.resizeend?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#remarks)

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to save MY.Settings afterwards.
This Should fix it.

> Note : Other replies also forgot to add [my.settings.save]

```
    ' app boots, form loads, and should set its screen location...
    Private Sub GUI_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        IF Not ( MY.Settings.Window_Location_Setting_X = 0  And  MY.Settings.Window_Location_Setting_Y = 0 )
            Me.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual
            Me.Location = New Point( MY.Settings.Window_Location_Setting_X, MY.Settings.Window_Location_Setting_Y )
        END IF
    END SUB
    
    ' I click and drag form to new locatin.......
    Private Sub GUI_LocationChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.LocationChanged
        MY.Settings.Window_Location_Setting_X = sender.Location.X
        MY.Settings.Window_Location_Setting_Y = sender.Location.y
        MY.Settings.save '<----------- Saves Locations (X & Y)
    End Sub
```

Comment: VB.Net Projects usually have ApplicationFramework enabled by default. This allows to specify that My.Settings is automatically saved when the application closes (`Save user settings on exit` option). Hence, it's not usually necessary to explicitly save the settings -- Anyway, as already commented about, when you assign the settings in `LocationChanged`, you save the default location of the Form, since `LocationChanged` is raised before `Load`

Answer (score -2):

Solution was to set a variable is_booting = true
at boot time, then set it false at end of form load.

then,

```
Private Sub GUI_LocationChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.LocationChanged
    IF Not is_booting
         PRINT("window moved sender.Location.X " & sender.Location.X )
         PRINT("window moved sender.Location.X " & sender.Location.Y )
        MY.Settings.Window_Location_Setting_X = sender.Location.X
        MY.Settings.Window_Location_Setting_Y = sender.Location.y
    END IF
End Sub
```

Comment: Your setting could(should) be a System.Drawing.Point.